# Why can't I resize the artboard in CC from center point and not adding only to right side for width?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard, creative-cloud

When resizing and adding any amount of pixels to the width of my artboard I cannot figure out how to add equal amounts to each side rather than just adding to the right side of my artboard. Previously when adding height or width to a canvas size it would give the option to anchor to center, top, bottom, left or right.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

**As noted in the comments, this question was posted in July of 2015** At that time the current release for Adobe products was **CC 2014**. In *that* release this was not possible. (as indicated by the very fact this question was posted) It is *very* common for Adobe to build a new feature with half-functionality. Then, in the next release, add more (expected) functionality. This was true for Photoshop artboards. CC2015 was released in June of 2015 (Roughly a month before this question was posted). So, it's not unexpected that *this* user was still on CC2014 where the functionality did not exist. Before down voting, one might want to check DATES on questions.

---

Original answer:
Because Adobe didn't build that functionality into Photoshop artboards... or Illustrator artboards for that matter.

There's *nothing* you can do about it.

Comment: +1 for a correct answer, NOT because I like this functionality. Srsly, this is such a basic feature I still can't believe it's not there.

Comment: Just a little correction: Illustrator has this functionality and it works the same way as resizing a canvas in Photoshop.

Comment: @go-meek Illustrator CC2015 **does** have this functionality. It was **not** present when this question was posed (2014). Adobe has improved the feature since implementation. It's impossible to update all answers to reflect software updates.

Comment: @Scott Unless I have issues with my eyes, it was asked this last july 2015. To my knowledge, this has been there for a long time but I could be wrong! In fact, it always annoyed me in the past that Illustrator always centered artboard by default; now it can be done anyway we want, it's great :D

Answer (score 0):

**FWIW:** You can switch to *Design Space* to change the size and position of the artboard(s). Rearrange your artboard and move your nested layers according to your changes. Should be an acceptable workaround.

**Photoshop Design Space (Preview)**

[image]

**Artboard Controls (Design Space)**

[image]

---

In *Photoshop Standard*, width and height is all you can set.

[image]

Comment: You don't need "Design Space" for this... simply highlighting the Artboard in the Layers Panel will allow you to adjust width and height of the artboard in the control bar. And.... this doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: I do know that and I did mention that. You get extra controls for X and Y, in Design Space. That's what I wanted to tell. I thought I made that clear. :-/

Comment: There aren't any "extra" controls in Design space.. they are just in a different location.

Comment: I don't see controls for X and Y in standard space.

Comment: They are right there in the [control bar (click to see)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DbDl3.jpg) when an artboard is highlighted in the Layers Panel.

Comment: No, there are no controls for X and Y position in your screenshot. Anyhow, my answer should have been a comment, but I wanted to add images to make it more helpful. At least I learned something today. Don't post an answer if you don't have an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A trick to change the artboard size to be centered:

**In Illustrator the functionality is there.**

Actually, since its beginning the resizing of the artboard [was only on the right side](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/whats-new-17-1.html#Other%20significant%20enhancements)!  The new CC versions permit you to resize from any side you want, including the center.

There's a few ways to achieve what you want:

Create an empty rectangle or square that is centered with your artwork.

Then select that shape, go in the menu "Object" > "Artboards", then select "fit to selected Art."

You can also simply go in the document setup, select "edit artboard" and resize the artboard by holding the command + option (alt) + shift key; it will resize the artboard equally on each side. Holding these keys together work as well to resize a lot of things in this way in pretty much all Adobe's software.

Finally, you can also go in the document setup, then "edit artboard" and manually enter the new dimensions on the top menu bar and put the "reference point" in the middle. It's the most precise way to do it. If you want to resize from left/right/top/middle instead, simply change that reference point.

[image: Resize artboard in Illustrator]

**In Photoshop:**

Unfortunately, the "command + option(alt) + shift" doesn't work on Photoshop artboard if you resize manually.

The only way you can do it is the good old lazy way, using guides, unfortunately; the same way as you maybe do sometimes when doing free transforms. I'm quite sure the option to do it automatically will be added on one of the next Photoshop versions.

Make your rulers visible (R) and then use the "Artboard tool" to see the handles on the corners and the ones at the center of your artboard. By default, you artboard is already centered.

Then add a vertical and an horizontal guide aligned with the middle handles... then resize manually your artboard or use the measurements in the menu bar. And then adjust your new artboard using these guides as reference, simply by aligning again the middle handles with the 2 guides.

Really not the perfect way but still faster then trying to measure the XY position for each situation.

[image: resizing manually centered artboard in Photoshop]

=======

<sup>Adobe CC 2015 released June 2015 (for paid subscribers):</sup>

<sup>http://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/the-2015-release-of-adobe-creative-cloud-is-here/</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**PHOTOSHOP**

The better way is just to do this is use the crop tool. instead of cropping manually to delete spaces, use: click and hold OPT/ATL button while you move the sides in crop mode.
i have done it even before CC, when it was just Photoshop.
i just did it for these screens and it works.

Steps as follows below:

1. center your images.

   for the CC2017, it gives you automatic grids to show you've hit the middle.
2. click on crop tool.

   this should create the boxes with constraints for you to move around, as shown below
   [image]
3. click and hold OPTION/ALT button.

   this should create a center base of which the crop will follow.
4. take any sides and drag them out.

[image]

hope my trick helps helps!

Answer (score -1):

When you select an Artboard in Photoshop you have handles left, right, top and bottom.

Select the right handle and drag to the desired size (you get a little tool tip with the size) then do the same to the left. Done

Answer (score -3):

**This is a work around.**

1 Draw a retangle in your artboard

2 Select and align the retangle to the center

3 Drag the artboard sides to match the retangle size and position

Comment: Hello Alwin, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your input. Please do not use a signature under your posts. Self-promotion should be limited to your profile page. Thanks for understanding! If you have any questions about the Stack Exchange model or this site in particular, have a look at the [tour]https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help].